# Authenticating a user to a Rails app through an URL emailed to them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am trying to build an application which will have a simple workflow where a user is emailed a specific URL which links to their account and provides them with a voucher for redemption.

Does anyone know of a good rails gem or other solution which would help me generate a user specific URL which is valid for a one time login to the application.

I've done a bunch of poking around on rubygems, github and stackoverflow and don't see anything obvious.

Hopefully this isn't an obvious question :)

Cheers
Kevin.

Comment: this is quite easy to code yourself. Just store this random token on a user (the token will be included in the url). When url is opened, you do something like `current_user = User.where(token: params[:token]).first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most popular gem for user authentication is Devise.
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

On the other hand Devise is very complex and it can be a little bit difficult to get the hang of it.

Comment: I was already using Devise on some other projects, but hadn't realized I could use it for token based as well.

It is working as I want now - thanks for pointing it out :)